# Matlab: two different variables take the same value

Tags: matlab

I want to implement recursion without a recursive function.
My code is the following:

```
for ff=1:6
    for step=i:-1:1       
       if (step == maxStep)

           R=-1;
           if(isTM =='1')
           R =1; 
           end
       else      

        DielectricConst =cell2mat(valueArray(step,1));
        Magnetic =cell2mat(valueArray(step,2));
        currentFreq = cell2mat(frequencies(ff));
        w = 2*3.1416*currentFreq;
         kiz =w*(DielectricConst*Magnetic - E0*M0*sin(angle).*sin(angle))^(1/2);

        DiConstPlusOne = cell2mat(valueArray(step+1,1));
        MagPlusOne =cell2mat( valueArray(step+1,2));
        kizPlusOne =w*(DiConstPlusOne*MagPlusOne - E0*M0*sin(angle).*sin(angle))^(1/2);

        res =((DiConstPlusOne*kiz)-(DielectricConst*kizPlusOne))/((DiConstPlusOne*kiz)+(DielectricConst*kizPlusOne)); 
        result =(res + R * exp(-((-1)^(1/2))*2*kizPlusOne*cell2mat( valueArray(step+1,3))))/(1+res*(R)*exp(-((-1)^(1/2))*2*kizPlusOne*cell2mat( valueArray(step+1,3))));

        R=result;
        end
%      disp(R);
    end

end
```

**res** and **result** values are always the same. Is it a pointer problem ?

Comment: A short description of what the code does would not hurt!

Comment: Recursion without a recursive function is just a loop.

Comment: Also, use `{}` indexing instead of calling `cell2mat` everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean? There are no pointers in Matlab...

Comment: BTW, you can use `pi` instead of `3.1416`...